# Mostrar nombre de los meses en español desde Laravel y Highcharts

Tags: javascript, laravel, highcharts

Estoy ejecutando una consulta por medio de Laravel y la estoy imprimiendo por medio de gráficas usando una librería llamada Highcharts. El inconveniente es que me imprime los meses en ingles y quiero que me los imprima en español, ¿hay alguna librería de que me muestre los meses en español desde el controlador de Laravel?

Aquí dejo el código del controlador de Laravel y la imagen de lo que me muestra

```
public function report_precebo_anual_conversion_final(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {

        $collection = Precebo::select(DB::raw('date_format(str_to_date(mes_traslado,"%m")
        ,"%M") as mes,avg(conversion_ajust_fin) as total'))
        ->where('año_destete',[$request->ano])
        ->groupBy('mes_traslado')->get();

        $arrayT = [];
        foreach ($collection as $value) {
            $arrayT[] = [$value->mes,$value->total];
        }
        // dd($arrayT);
        return response()->json(['status'=>'success','data'=>$arrayT],200); 
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba  Carbon ,  http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: este objeto debe venir de algún lugar no??
`$value->mes` te recomiendo que revise la documentación si existe algún parámetro de configuración de lenguaje y si no existe te toca idear una funcion genérica que tome el valor y lo convierta de idioma.

Comment: si miras bien en el controlador hay dos alias, esos nombres q estan en el array son los alias de la consulta

Comment: @JuanEstebanYarce desde mysql 5.0.25 puedes hacer `SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES'` y creo que resolverías el problema. pero no se si tu query lo soporte. tambien puedes usar es_MX

Comment: pero en laravel como hago para implementar ese SET en mi controlador en base de datos me los muestra en español pero en el controlador me los muestra en ingles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varias formas en la que puedes solucionar tu problema de internacionalización.

Opciones:

- En tu base de datos:
  Puedes lograr que tu base de datos devuelva el nombre del mes en tu idioma [configurando la localidad](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locale-support.html) y usando la [función monthname](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) como en este ejemplo:

  ```sql
  SET lc_time_names = 'es_Es';
  select monthname(now());
  ```

  El inconveniente con esto, es que tu software tendrá que configurar los locales en cada consulta si quieres atender a mas de un idioma.
- En tu controlador:

  Puedes devolver desde tu consulta el numero de mes con la [función month](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) de la siguiente forma:

  ```sql
  select month(now());
  ```

  Cuando tengas el dato, en php puedes hacer algo como:

  ```php
  <?php

  $months = [1 => 'enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', '...']; // los nombres empiezan de 1 en sql
  echo $months[2];

  /* en tu caso... */
  $arrayT[] = [$months[$value->numero_mes], $value->total];
  ```

  Ahora si aún quieres devolver los nombres de los meses en ingles desde la base de datos:

  ```
  <?php

  $value->mes // esto es January, February, etc.
  ```

  debes cambiar el valor del array de (1) a el nombre del mes en ingles:

  ```
  <?php

  $months = ['january' => 'enero', 'february' => 'febrero', 'march' => 'marzo', '...' => '...'];
  ```

  Puedes mirarte el ejemplo en [este link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa5ee11482b163c90691a997de3277d7ed154e28). Recuerda que para usar los meses como indices numéricos debes devolver un numero desde la base de datos.

  Ademas si usas Laravel puedes usar la [internacionalización que tiene por defecto](https://laravel.com/docs/master/localization) declarando los meses en `lang/es/meses.php` (este es un ejemplo) de la siguiente forma:

  ```php
  <?php

  return [
      1 => 'Enero',
      'Febrero',
      'Marzo'
  ];
  ```

  luego en tu controlador:

  ```php
  $arrayT[] = [__('meses.' . $value->numero_mes), $value->total];
  ```
- En el cliente:

  Lo anterior es válido también en el cliente. Puedes enviar el indice y procesarlo en Js antes de mostrar los datos en tus gráficos o bien puedes usar las funciones de formateo de Highcharts como en [este ejemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-formatter-linked/) de la propiedad [xAxis.labels.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter). Mira este ejemplo:

```js
let months = {
    1: 'enero',
    2: 'febrero',
    3: 'marzo'
};

Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Ejemplo'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: [1, 2, 3],
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return months[this.value];
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 500px"></div>
```

Comment: gran parte de las opciones me sirven pero tengo un pequeño problema cuando hago el array de months me dice q january osea enero no esta definido

Comment: En js o php? Intenta copiar y pegar los nombres de variables, quizá es un error tipográfico

Comment: en el php cuando haces el array de los meses osea este $months = [1 => 'enero','febrero','....'] me dice q enero no esta definido lo q me parece muy raro $arrayT[] = [$months[$value->numero_mes], $value->total]; obviamente le cambio numero_mes por mes que es el alias de la base de datos

Comment: Edité un poco la respuesta. Debes usar indices numéricos solo si en tu consulta SQL usas la función `month()` de lo contrario tienes que usar el texto en inglés como clave, ej: `'november' => 'noviembre'`

Comment: en MYSQL estoy usando esta funcion DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(mes_traslado,"%m") ,"%M") AS mes, debido a que el campo solo tiene el mes, no toda la cadena de fecha q es año-mes-dia, solo tiene mes pero si utilizo eso mismo no habria problema

Answer (score 1):

Hay que ***set***-ear el Locale del idioma, es PHP a saco ***setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES')*** y quitar el utf8 por los acentos del español meidante Crabon ***Carbon::setUtf8(false)***

*Cuidado tienes que tener el idioma en el servidor instalada. 
Ejecuta mediante SSH*

> locale -a

*Te dirá los idiomas que tiene la maquina si no tienes es español o el idioma que necesites,  hay que instalarlo pero eso ese otro tipo de problema que debería ir a otro hilo según entiendo yo*

```
public function report_precebo_anual_conversion_final(Request $request)
{

    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');
    Carbon::setUtf8(false);
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $collection = Precebo::select(DB::raw('mes_traslado as mes, avg(conversion_ajust_fin) as total'))
        ->where('año_destete',[$request->ano])
        ->groupBy('mes_traslado')->get();
        $arrayT = [];
        foreach ($collection as $value) {
            $arrayT[] = [Carbon::setToStringFormat('F'); Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2018-01-23')->formatLocalized('%B'), $value->total];
        }
        // dd($arrayT);
        return response()->json(['status'=>'success','data'=>$arrayT],200); 
    }
}
```

Comment: me tirar un error de sintaxis en la parte de setTostrinformat esa coma no debe ir ahi, no sera donde esta coma debe estar es una flecha??

Answer (score 1):

Esta respuesta no sustituye a la aceptada, la complementa.

Queda una opcion que puedes tener en cuenta si quieres presentar en varios idiomas y es la de usar "Localization" de Laravel:

En el archivo de idioma (en mi caso general.php).

(Vease que están las formas más habituales de escribir un mes) :

```
    'mes'=>'{1}enero|{2}febrero|{3}marzo|{4}abril|{5}mayo|{6}junio|{7}julio|{8}agosto|{9}septiembre|{10}octubre|{11}noviembre|{12}diciembre',
    'Mes'=>'{1}Enero|{2}Febrero|{3}Marzo|{4}Abril|{5}Mayo|{6}Junio|{7}Julio|{8}Agosto|{9}Septiembre|{10}Octubre|{11}Noviembre|{12}Diciembre',
    'mesabr'=>'{1}ene|{2}feb|{3}mar|{4}abr|{5}may|{6}jun|{7}jul|{8}ago|{9}sep|{10}oct|{11}nov|{12}dic',
    'Mesabr'=>'{1}Ene|{2}Feb|{3}Mar|{4}Abr|{5}May|{6}Jun|{7}Jul|{8}Ago|{9}Sep|{10}Oct|{11}Nov|{12}Dic',
    'MESabr'=>'{1}ENE|{2}FEB|{3}MAR|{4}ABR|{5}MAY|{6}JUN|{7}JUL|{8}AGO|{9}SEP|{10}OCT|{11}NOV|{12}DIC',
```

Y dónde quiera usarse:

```
// Para $value->numero_mes=2

trans_choice('general.mes', $value->numero_mes)
//devuelve: febrero

trans_choice('general.Mes', $value->numero_mes)
//devuelve: Febrero

trans_choice('general.mesabr', $value->numero_mes)
//devuelve: feb

trans_choice('general.Mesabr', $value->numero_mes)
//devuelve: Feb

trans_choice('general.MESabr', $value->numero_mes)
//devuelve: FEB
```

Así tienes cubiertos todos los idiomas que quieras usar sin mayores complicaciones.